# Social network dataset

Tags: dataset

I'am looking for social network datasets for determining the strength of (acquaintance, friendship, family ,professional,...) relationships
can any one help me to find it 
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

A standard source of network data is the [UCI Repository](http://networkdata.ics.uci.edu/index.php). Software packages also usually come with their own illustrative datasets, for example [Gephi](https://gephi.org/) (free) and [various R packages](http://jeromyanglim.blogspot.co.nz/2009/08/social-network-analysis-resources-for-r.html) (also free) and [Pajek](http://vlado.fmf.uni-lj.si/pub/networks/pajek/) (free).

Comment: how to know the strenth of relationship from this dataset through gephi.

Comment: I tested the data from a social network but I do not know the strength of relationships that links users and their kinds